# Python 'raise' without arguments: what is "the last exception that was active in the current scope"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, exception, raise

Python's documentation says:

> If no expressions are present, `raise` re-raises the last exception that was active in the current scope.

(Python 3: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#raise; Python 2.7: https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#raise.)

However, the notion of "last active" seems to have changed.  Witness the following code sample:

```py
#
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
print('Python version =', sys.version)

try:
    raise Exception('EXPECTED')
except:
    try:
        raise Exception('UNEXPECTED')
    except:
        pass
    raise # re-raises UNEXPECTED for Python 2, and re-raises EXPECTED for Python 3
```

which results in something I didn't expect with Python 2:

```
Python version = 2.7.15 (v2.7.15:ca079a3ea3, Apr 30 2018, 16:30:26) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./x", line 10, in <module>
    raise Exception('UNEXPECTED')
Exception: UNEXPECTED
```

but has the expected (by me) result with Python 3:

```
Python version = 3.6.8 (default, Feb 14 2019, 22:09:48)
[GCC 7.4.0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./x", line 7, in <module>
    raise Exception('EXPECTED')
Exception: EXPECTED
```

and

```
Python version = 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 23:09:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./x", line 7, in <module>
    raise Exception('EXPECTED')
Exception: EXPECTED
```

So what does "the last ... active" mean?  Is there some documentation on this breaking change?  Or is this a Python 2 bug?

And more importantly: What is the best way to make this work in Python 2?  (Preferably such that the code will keep working in Python 3.)

---

*Note* that if one changes the code to

```py
#
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
print('Python version =', sys.version)

def f():
    try:
        raise Exception('UNEXPECTED')
    except:
        pass

try:
    raise Exception('EXPECTED')
except:
    f()
    raise # always raises EXPECTED
```

then things start to work for Python 2 as well:

```
Python version = 2.7.15 (v2.7.15:ca079a3ea3, Apr 30 2018, 16:30:26) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./x", line 13, in <module>
    raise Exception('EXPECTED')
Exception: EXPECTED
```

I'm considering to switch to that...

Comment: Related: https://cosmicpercolator.com/2016/01/13/exception-leaks-in-python-2-and-3/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Python 2 behavior is not so much a *bug* as a *design flaw*. It was addressed in Python 3.0 by adding the exception chaining features. The closest thing to documentation of this change can be found in [PEP 3134 -- Exception Chaining and Embedded Tracebacks](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3134/#motivation)
 motivation:

> During the handling of one exception (exception A), it is possible that another exception (exception B) may occur. In today's Python (version 2.4), if this happens, exception B is propagated outward and exception A is lost.

This is exactly what you're seeing in 2.7: EXPECTED (A) was lost because UNEXPECTED (B) appeared and overwrote it. With the newer exception chaining features in Python 3, the full context of both errors can be preserved via `__cause__` and `__context__` attributes on exception instances.

For a more direct cross-compatible workaround, I would encourage you to keep the references manually, explicitly show which error is being re-raised, and as usual avoid bare `except` statements (which are always too broad):

```
try:
    raise Exception('EXPECTED')
except Exception as err_expected:
    try:
        raise Exception('UNEXPECTED')
    except Exception as err_unexpected:
        pass
    raise err_expected
```

Should you wish to suppress the exception-chaining feature in a cross-compatible way, you can do that by setting `err_expected.__cause__ = None` before re-raising.

Answer (score 0):

`raise` uses the same information as `sys.exc_info`, which documents [both](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info) [behaviors](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info).  Since the per-frame behavior that your workaround exploits is documented, that’s the way to go.

[PEP 3110](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3110) made several changes to the `except` statement.  I believe it included this one, but the only thing explicitly mentioned is that an exception stored by `as` is discarded when leaving the `except`.

Comment: This PEP 3110 is mostly unrelated to OP question. The discarding of exception when leaving the except block is about working around an `exception -> traceback -> stack frame -> exception` reference cycle that the new `__traceback__` attribute caused.

Comment: @wim: Well, the behavior seems to have been changed by r62847, but I haven’t found what (other?) PEP that might be.